# Error : exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE' exceptionMessage='Must send a concrete entity type.'

Tags: java, wsdl

```
 private static void createCustomer() {
        System.out.println("Creating");
        Customer__c[] createCust = new Customer__c[5];
        try {
            Customer__c customer = new Customer__c();
            customer.setCustomer_Name__c("Varma");;
            customer.setBranch__c("Pallavaram");
            customer.setAccount_No__c("33443356");
            createCust[0]= customer;
            SaveResult[] saveResults = connection.create(createCust);
            if(saveResults[0].isSuccess()) {
                System.out.println("Successfully created customer ! - id:" + saveResults[0].getId());
            }else {
                Error[] errors = saveResults[0].getErrors();
                    System.out.println("Error :" + errors[0].getMessage());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hi, Here is my code.
This is some few code where my error occurs..
Where Customer__c is my object name and the error indicates the line
**"SaveResult[] saveResults = connection.create(createCust);"** 
Help would be great .
Thanks in advance

Comment: why you are using connection.create() in your code?

Comment: So that it will create a new record in my indicated Sobject (Customer__c)

Comment: Connection is a variable for function ConnectorConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one element created, but the array is 5 elements long. This would produce the error you've seen. Try this instead:

```
Customer__c[] createCust = new Customer__c[1]; // Allocate space for 1 element.
```

Comment: Thanks ! Appreciate the help